# Notification and indicator applets in Gnome Classic

Tags: server, indicator, gnome-classic, notification-area

I am running a GUI-enabled Ubuntu 11.10 Server installation using Gnome Classic. I have just one panel which has the following items:

Power button
Apps/Places
A few launchers
Taskbar
Workspace switcher
Notification area
Clock.

My problem is that the notification area, which I want there for background services icons (SpiderOak etc) also includes a Volume Control and a Microphone Volume Control icon, neither or which is required. How do I get rid of these?

I have searched around and found some references to an Indicator Applet, which appears to be different from the Notification Area applet, but I don't find it in the list of options to add to my panel when I Win-Alt-Right-Click the panel. Not sure if I should be trying to install that rather than Notification Area?

Answer (score 2):

By default only 'indicator-applet-complete' is available in the new gnome, but you can install more tailored indicator applets:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet indicator-applet-session
```

Perhaps these can give you what you want.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package indicator-applet-complete

Comment: sudo apt-get install indicator-applet
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package indicator-applet is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'indicator-applet' has no installation candidate

Comment: get the same error for indicator-applet-session as indicator-applet